# Angular 2 popup form on-click

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I need a pop-up screen on click in angular 2. A pop-up screen will include different tabs and form I tried with angular2-modal but it has only prompt are alert but not sure whether it support custom form creation.

If angular2-model support custom form how to do else Is there any other package which supports to achieve my task.

My code:

```
***users.component.html*** 

<input type="checkbox" name="scheduler2" (click)="helpWindow($event)"> 


***users.component.ts***

 helpWindow(event) {
    this.modal.alert()
        .size('lg')
        .isBlocking(true)
        .keyboard(27)
        .showClose(true)
        .title('A simple Alert style modal window')
        .body(`
            <h4>Alert is a classic (title/body/footer) 1 button modal window that 
            does not block.</h4>
            <b>Configuration:</b>
            <ul>
                <input type="text" name="text" />
            </ul>`)
        .open();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is angular2-modal open function:

```
  /**
   * Opens a modal window inside an existing component.
   * @param content The content to display, either string, template ref 
 or a component.
  * @param config Additional settings.
  * @returns {Promise<DialogRef>}
   */
   open(content: ContainerContent, config?: OverlayConfig): 
     Promise<DialogRef<any>> {... }
```

As you see you can provide a ref to template or custom modal component.
See [bootstrap-demo-page](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal/blob/master/src/demo/app/bootstrap-demo/bootstrap-demo-page/bootstrap-demo-page.ts) for details.

Comment: I have started using it and it works fine. I have one small query how to reduce or increase the width of the pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular2 material. It gas a nice dialog where you can inject any component and that component will show up in that model. It also come with lots of nice features like afterClose(subscriber). You can pass data to its child component.